# How do I print out a sequence of answers using a for loop in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

The question might be a little vague still so allow me to elaborate. My goal is to calculate download speeds based on user input. So a sample output is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptkcO.png).

So I've gone ahead and asked for user input using the following code (this part totally works but just to give you the bigger picture)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int minFileSize, maxFileSize, maxDLSpeed, minDLSpeed;
int time;


//first we get user input for minimum size and download speeds
printf("Enter a minimum file size: ");
scanf("%d", &minFileSize);
//after this condition is satisfied..
while (minFileSize <= 0 ) {
    printf("Invalid input. Try again: \n");
    scanf("%d", &minFileSize);

    while(getchar() != '\n' );                        //clears caches
}
//program continues
printf("Enter a minimum download speed (MB/s): ");
scanf("%d", &minDLSpeed);
while (minDLSpeed <= 0) {
    printf("Invalid input. Try again: ");
    scanf("%d", &minDLSpeed);

    while ( getchar() != '\n' );
}
printf("Enter a maximum file size (MB): ");
scanf("%d", &maxFileSize);
while (maxFileSize < minFileSize) {                   //maxFileSize can't be lower than minFileSize
    printf("Invalid input. Try again: ");
    scanf("%d", &maxFileSize);

    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
printf("Enter maximum download speed (MB/s): ");
scanf("%d", &maxDLSpeed);
while (maxDLSpeed < minDLSpeed) {
    printf("Invalid input. Try again: ");
    scanf("%d", &maxDLSpeed);

    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```

where the while (getchar() != '\n') just clears the cache so we can proceed to the next input.

After getting the user input, I then use a nested for-loop to loop through the minimum file size all the way to the maximum size (so it stops when it reaches the maximum size, which is based on what the user enters) and then do the same thing for the minimum download speed and maximum download speed. **Then each time the loop iterates, its supposed to output the download speed, which is (file size / download speed) So i/j represents this**

Here's the loop I used for that

```
for (int i = minFileSize; i <= maxFileSize; i++)
{
    for (int j = minDLSpeed; j<= maxDLSpeed; j++) {

        time = i / j;     
    };
}
```

*Phew* If you've read that far, thank you! Now my question is how do I print the output in the format that I showed above, so that each time the loop runs, it prints out the correct download speed based on the file size and download speed.

Comment: Your question contains a huge snippet which is ultimately irrelevant but stays ambiguous about what you really need to do. I don't understand what your problem is - is it just about printing an integer in the loop? `printf("%d\n", time);` ?

Comment: So my question is to print out an integer in the loop but to do so continously until we reach the max value. So if our minimum file size is 8 and our minimum download speed is 9, it should print out that output (so file size divided by download speed) and THEN loop to the next one; so now it goes min file size of 9 and mini download speed of 10 and stops when it reaches the maximum download and file size inputs (which the user gives initially)

Comment: I still don't understand. Exactly how is that different from calling `printf()` in the inner loop? Is your question about the printing or about the logic of your loop conditionals?

Comment: My question I suppose pertains to both. if you look below @mhawke 's reponse, its basically taking the user inputs and looping through it for each individual download speed and file size, and then printing that specific value. So file size 8 and download speed 9 would give you .89 and then you go for file size 9 and download speed 10 and print that all the way until you reach the max file and download spees (lets say  they are 13 and 12, respectively)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems to be the wrong way around. The outer for loop should be for the download speeds, and the inner loop for the file sizes:

```
for (int dl_speed=minDLSpeed; dl_speed<=maxDLSpeed; dl_speed++) {
    printf("%6.2fMB/s |", (float)dl_speed);
    for (int file_size=minFileSize; file_size<=maxFileSize; file_size++)
        printf("%6.2fs", (float)file_size / dl_speed);
    printf("\n");
}
```

That should give you the body of the table. You will need to add the header lines too and you should now be able to work out how to do that given the code shown above. For your input values you will get a table that looks like this:

```
Enter a minimum file size: 8
Enter a minimum download speed (MB/s): 9
Enter a maximum file size (MB): 13
Enter maximum download speed (MB/s): 12
  9.00MB/s |  0.89s  1.00s  1.11s  1.22s  1.33s  1.44s
 10.00MB/s |  0.80s  0.90s  1.00s  1.10s  1.20s  1.30s
 11.00MB/s |  0.73s  0.82s  0.91s  1.00s  1.09s  1.18s
 12.00MB/s |  0.67s  0.75s  0.83s  0.92s  1.00s  1.08s
```

Comment: Ah I see, so we need to declare additional ints -- dl_speed & file_size -- in addition to the initial max and in speed and file size variables.. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: You need variables for the for loops, yes. You can name them whatever you like, however, using descriptive names instead of `i` and `j` makes the code more readable.

Comment: Two questions... First is why did you use 6.2 in the first for loop? Second is was my original question clear to you? I'm trying to get feedback on asking questions here (as basic as that seems -- turns out asking the right question is half the battle when you don't know fully know what to do!) I assume you were able to follow relatively easily but it was a lot of text so I'd like to know if I was able to demonstrate what I wanted to happen.

Comment: Your question shows good effort, though it is always worth a stop by [**StackOverflow - Help Center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and browsing the topics. Just a little phraseology nit, `while (getchar() != '\n);` clears the ***input buffer*** (e.g. `stdin`) not the *cache*.

Comment: @HassanKamara: you should do some reading about the format string for `printf()`.  `6.2f` specifies that the corresponding argument to `printf()` should be treated as a `float` (that's the `f` part) with 2 digit precision (that's the `.2` part). The `6` specifies a field width of 6 characters in which the output is right justified.

Comment: @HassanKamara: re your second question: was it clear to me? If I managed to provide the correct answer then I suppose that it was clear. I had to read the question a few times, but from the second snippet of code it was clear to me what you were trying to do, so it was easy to provide an answer. The first code snippet is largely irrelevant and I didn't bother to read it. If I successfully answered your question you should consider upvoting it and accepting it.

Comment: @mhawke: re 6.2f, I'm just starting out in C, having previously worked with mainly Javascript and PHP, so there's a lot of new stuff to go get used to. Thank you though for taking the time to help me out;